# List View gets cleared when orientation changes in Android (using a customAdapter, List<Class Object>)

Tags: android-listview, android-custom-view, android-orientation, device-orientation, orientation-changes

In my app, I implemented a Listview with a CustomAdapter. The Customadapter is made from a List object, that is, `List<ClassObject>`. And the addition to this `List<ClassObject>` is dynamic. And this ListView element has one button field, which is used to delete that selected ClassObject from `List<ClassObject>`.

And all these works fine in one orientation. But when orientation changes to another, the list view gets clear, and I checked by code, `List<ClassObject>` gets clear and `List<ClassObject>.size()` return zero.

And I'm using different layout for portrait orientation and landscape orientation.

I tried android:ConfigChanges="Orientation|Screensize" in manifest.xml, it's prevent my data but it hold one to portrait layout even when change to landscape and it's messing my layout.

I want to know how to prevent my data with matching the separate layout for landscape and portrait.

The app should work API level SDK 8 to higher 15.

Please tell me the difference between `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outInstanceState)` and `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()`.

And when I look onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() on developer.android, they says it's deprecated in API level 13. So what should we use instead?

I did figure out to save the data somehow using below code.

```
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle) {
    // save your data
 //lstRoughDetailsPL is an object of List<Rough>
    outState.putSerializable(""+R.id.lstSO,(Serializable) lstRoughDetailsPL);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    // read your previously saved data
        //lstRoughDetailsPL is an global object of List<Rough>
    lstRoughDetailsPL = (List<Rough>)savedInstanceState.getSerializable(""+R.id.lstSO);
    FillGrid();// used do fill the list view by looping around the List<Rough> and passing values as 4 string[] to a CustomAdapter which has 4 textview in each list entry.

}
```

but when call come or open another app from notification slide, my activity gets crush. say "Unfortunately, MyRoughWorkOutApp has Stopped"

What I have to do?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.
I changed my class to parcelable class and then passed the object of ArrayList to bundle.

Now, Everything works fine and perfect. If anyone need help, feel free to say..